# How can we pass image variables in jinja2/weasyprint python

Tags: python, variables, jinja2, weasyprint

the problem is that i am trying to create an image variable in python using jinja2 and weasyprint and then, i want to pass that image variable in my HTML template (html_out).

I was successful in creating the image variable and it appears in my variable explorer. But passing it to the HTML template by including it in my dictionary was only trouble.

```py
#this is my image variable
art_work = Image.open('D:/Course/report-automation/Huaweii.png')

#this is my dictionary

template_vars = {"title": title, "start_date": start_date, "end_date": end_date, "price": price, 
                 "total_Impressions": total_impressions, "art_work": art_work, "total_Clicks": total_clicks,
                 "cpm":cpm, "percentage_mobile": percentage_mobile}
```

```
below is the html template with my variable holder: 

 <div class="image-wrapper">
        {{ art_work }}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display image you should use `<img>` tag. Also, just pass the src of image in dictionary.

```html
      <div class="image-wrapper">
         <img src=" {{ art_work }}" />
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Atul. But unfortunately, when generating PDF, the image does not appear on my report.

Comment: You said you have created the image in variable, the you need to save it and pass the src location of image where you have saved it. Then image tag will render it.